# Read data from file into 2d array and sum over specific arrays using C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to parse a file by reading in a file into arrays and sum over arrays after hitting specific keywords in the file. This is what I already wrote but I have three questions regarding the written code below:
1) Now I am only able to sum over each row after string " 15". How can I include also string " 16" to sum over each row in order to
2) give out the sum of the two rows " 15" and " 16" as a total value
3) because right now the code loops only over each row without getting the line of " 16":

**This is the input data:**

```
 15  0.476  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.001  

 16  0.476  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.001 

 15  0.000 -0.000 -0.000  0.000 -0.000  0.000  0.000 

 16 -0.000 -0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000 -0.000 -0.000 

 15  0.000  0.000 -0.000 -0.000  0.000  0.000 -0.000 

 16  0.000 -0.000  0.000 -0.000  0.000 -0.000  0.000

 15  0.476 -0.000  0.000 -0.000 -0.000 -0.000  0.001 

 16  0.476 -0.000 -0.000  0.000  0.000 -0.000  0.001
```

**This is the output after running the code:**

```
number of rows  --> 4

number of cols --> 9

15.000 0.476 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.001

15.000 0.000 -0.000 -0.000 0.000 -0.000 0.000 0.000

15.000 0.000 0.000 -0.000 -0.000 0.000 0.000 -0.000

15.000 0.476 -0.000 0.000 -0.000 -0.000 -0.000 0.001

sum of each row: 0.477

sum of each row: 0.000

sum of each row: 0.000

sum of each row: 0.477
```

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

bool found(const string& line);

int main()
{
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    string line;
    double x;
    double array[100][100], rowtotal[100] = {0}, columntotal[100]={0};
    ofstream File;
    ifstream in("data.txt");
    File.open("extracted_data.txt",ios::app);
    File.setf(ios::fixed);
    File.setf(ios::showpoint);
    File.precision(3);

    if(in.fail()) 
    {
        cerr << " File can not be opened ";
        return -1;
    }

    File << "\n" << endl;
    while(in.good()) 
    {
        while(getline(in, line)) 
        {
            if (found(line)) 
            {
                istringstream stream(line);
                col = 0;
                while(stream >> x) 
                {
                    array[row][col] = x;
                    col++;
                }
                row++;
            }
        }
    }

    File << "number of rows  --> " << row << endl;
    File << "number of cols --> " << col << endl;
    File << " " << endl;

    for(int i=0; i < row; i++) 
    {
        for(int j=0; j < col; j++) 
        {
            File << array[i][j] << " ";
        }
        File << "\n" << endl;
    }


    for(int i=0; i < 4; i++)
    {  
        for (int j=1; j < 8; j++) 
        {
            rowtotal[i] = rowtotal[i] + array[i][j];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    { 
        File << "sum of each row: " << rowtotal[i] << endl;
    }

    File.close();
    in.close();
    return 0;
}

bool found(const string& line)
{
    return (line.find(" 15")!= string::npos);
}
```

I am grateful for any hint or advice how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance for your time and effort!

Best wishes,

DaveS

Comment: I have to say I'm not sure about what you wanna do, can you be a bit more precise? Or is it just me who doesn't understand?

Comment: I would like to loop over the two rows after hitting integers "15" and "16" (keep going like this through the whole data) so that it should give out the sum of e.g.: 15 0.476 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.001 and 16 0.476 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.001 , yielding a total sum of: 0.954. And then it continues with the next 2 rows... Anyway, I edited the code which I posted in the beginning. I guess that I only need to loop over the 2 rows and get total of these rows as explained above. In this sense, my problem is that I can not get the code to sum over the two rows. Thanks again!

Comment: If I understand your code, right now you only add the values of your line in your array when it start with "15", so you can't work with the "16" lines, am I right?

Comment: Yeah, right! I want to include also the lines with "16". How can I accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you only have lines beginnig with " 15" and " 16"? Or is it possible to have some other combinations? And if so, do you want to ignore every other combination than " 15" and " 16", or do you want to work with these?

Comment: In fact, there are also lines beginning with integers " 1"," 2"," 3",...but I want to ignore these. I only need to work with " 15" and " 16" and get the sum of these two rows.

Comment: Are you trying to count the total rows and columns in the file? And then afterwards sum up the values of each row?

Comment: Yeah, I counted the number of rows and columns in order to have a better control over the code. It is just a check for myself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I think I found a solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

void addRow(double row[100], istringstream& stream, int& col)
{
    double x;
    col = 0;

    while(stream >> x) 
    {
        row[col] += x;
        col++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    string line;
    int firstNb = 0;
    double array[100][100], rowtotal[100] = {0}, columntotal[100]={0};
    ofstream File;
    ifstream in("data.txt");
    File.open("extracted_data.txt",ios::app);
    File.setf(ios::fixed);
    File.setf(ios::showpoint);
    File.precision(3);

    if(in.fail()) 
    {
        cerr << " File can not be opened ";
        return -1;
    }

    File << "\n" << endl;
    while(in.good()) 
    {
        while(getline(in, line)) 
        {            
            istringstream stream(line);
            firstNb = atoi(line.c_str());
            if (firstNb == 15 || firstNb == 16)
                addRow(array[row], stream, col);

            if (firstNb == 16)
                row++;
        }
    }

    File << "number of rows  --> " << row << endl;
    File << "number of cols --> " << col << endl;
    File << " " << endl;

    for(int i=0; i < row; i++) 
    {
        for(int j=0; j < col; j++) 
        {
            File << array[i][j] << " ";
        }
        File << "\n" << endl;
    }


    for(int i=0; i < 4; i++)
    {  
        for (int j=1; j < 8; j++) 
        {
            rowtotal[i] = rowtotal[i] + array[i][j];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    { 
        File << "sum of each row: " << rowtotal[i] << endl;
    }

    File.close();
    in.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Like this, you only increment row when the first number is 16, and when it is 15 or 16, you add the following values in the same row.

Then in your program i would better use C++ specific tools, like vector.
Vectors are like arrays, but you can dinamycally add elements, so it's size is not constant. Like this, you would not have to use (ugly) arrays with defined size, which is not safe for your program (imagine there are 102 row, your program will explode).

If you any question, go on :)

**UPDATE:** Okay so I worked a bit on this a I finished with that, I find it a lot more logical to first read every values, and then work with them. It's not optimized or nothing, but it's logical and it work well :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    string line;
    int firstNb = 0;
    vector<vector<double>> values;
    vector<vector<double>> result;
    vector<double> rowtotal;
    ofstream File;
    ifstream in("data.txt");
    File.open("extracted_data.txt",ios::app);
    File.setf(ios::fixed);
    File.setf(ios::showpoint);
    File.precision(3);

    if(in.fail()) 
    {
        cerr << "File can not be opened" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    File << "\n" << endl;

    // Store every number
    while(in.good()) 
    {
        while(getline(in, line)) 
        {            
            istringstream stream(line);
            vector<double> tmp;
            double x;

            while (stream >> x)
              tmp.push_back(x);

            if (tmp.size() > 0)
              values.push_back(tmp);
        }
    }

    // Check if the column number is constant
    col = values[0].size();
    for (unsigned i = 1; i < values.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (values[i].size() != col)
        {
            cerr << "Row with different column number" << endl;
            return -1;
        }
    }

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i)
    {
        // If we encounter a 15 we add it as row
        if (values[i][0] == 15.0)
          result.push_back(values[i]);

        // If we encounter a 16 we add it to the last row
        if (values[i][0] == 16.0)
        {
            for (unsigned j = 0; j < values[i].size(); ++j)
              result.back()[j] += values[i][j];
        }
    }

    row = result.size();

    File << "number of rows  --> " << row << endl;
    File << "number of cols --> " << col << endl;
    File << " " << endl;

    for(int i=0; i < row; i++) 
    {
        for(int j=0; j < col; j++) 
        {
            File << result[i][j] << " ";
        }
        File << "\n" << endl;
    }


    for(int i=0; i < row; i++)
    {  
        rowtotal.push_back(0.0);
        for (int j=1; j < col; j++) 
        {
            rowtotal[i] += result[i][j];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    { 
        File << "sum of each row: " << rowtotal[i] << endl;
    }

    File.close();
    in.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for both suggestions and wonderful solutions to the problem!!! Yeah, right now I realized that I have a lot of data in my data file :/ (2.500.000 lines) and the code terminates with "segmentation fault" ...If I want to edit the code by increasing the size of the arrays, it gives me error of "size of array is too large" when I want to compile it. How would I rewrite this code using vectors in order to read all the data in? Thank you again, both of you for taking your time, I really appreciate it! P.s.: I think you have clairvoyant skills seeing already my problem which will happen :)

Comment: No it's just because it's always better to prevent the most extreme cases. Here it was logical to have a lot more data, and it's always better to create modular code, because when you want to modify your program, that's all you want. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading you right, you want to sum rows matching your chosen ID's such as 15 and 16. And to sum columns for the same ID's. I've added another dimension to the `rowtotal` and `columntotal` arrays - this represents the total for each chosen ID. `groupby` array has the ID's you want to sum. The `rowcount` and `columncount` arrays count the items in the total. 0 means there is no corresponding total.

```
int main()
{
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    string line;
    double x;
    double array[100][100], rowtotal[10][100] = {}, columntotal[10][100] = {}, rowcount[10][100] = {}, columncount[10][100] = {};
    ofstream File;
    ifstream in("so40347495_data.txt");
    File.open("so40347495_output.txt", ios::app);
    File.setf(ios::fixed);
    File.setf(ios::showpoint);
    File.precision(3);

    if (in.fail())
    {
        cerr << " File can not be opened ";
        return -1;
    }


    File << "\n" << endl;
    while (in.good())
    {
        while (getline(in, line))
        {
            istringstream stream(line);
            col = 0;
            while (stream >> x)
            {
                array[row][col] = x;
                col++;
            }
            row++;
        }
    }

    File << "number of rows  --> " << row << endl;
    File << "number of cols --> " << col << endl;
    File << " " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            File << array[i][j] << " ";
        }
        File << "\n" << endl;
    }

    // Do sums
    int groupby[] = { 15, 16 };         // the ID numbers we want to sum by
    int groups = sizeof(groupby)/sizeof(groupby[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)   {
        for (int j = 1; j < col; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < groups; k++)
            if (groupby[k] == array[i][0])
            {
                rowtotal[k][i] += array[i][j];
                rowcount[k][i]++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)  {
        for (int k = 0; k < groups; k++)
        {
            if (rowcount[k][i] > 0 )
                File << "row " << i << " total for ID " << groupby[k] << " " << rowtotal[k][i] << endl;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < col; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < groups; k++)
            if (groupby[k] == array[i][0])
            {
                columntotal[k][j] += array[i][j];
                columncount[k][j]++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int j = 1; j < col; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < groups; k++)
        {
            if (columncount[k][j] > 0)
            {
                File << "column " << j << " total for ID " << groupby[k] << " " << columntotal[k][j] << endl;
            }
        }
    }


    File.close();
    in.close();
    return 0;
}
```