# Read data from file and sum over specific columns after hitting specific line (string) using C++

Tags: c++

I decided to open a new thread even if the problem is already solved partially but the problem is another one right now ([Read data from file into 2d array and sum over specific arrays using C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40347495/read-data-from-file-into-2d-array-and-sum-over-specific-arrays-using-c/40350909#40350909)). Nevertheless, here is what I want to read in:

---

Calculation
Number of points: 200 # Atoms: 4

Point 1 : 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 Weighting = 0.00500000

Energy 1 # with weighting 1.00000000

Atom a b c d
1 0.476 0.000 0.000 0.100
2 0.476 0.000 0.000 0.100
1 0.000 -0.000 -0.000 0.200
2 -0.000 -0.000 0.000 0.200

Energy 2 # with weighting 1.00000000

Atom a b c d
1 0.476 0.000 0.000 0.300
2 0.476 0.000 0.000 0.300
1 0.000 -0.000 -0.000 0.400
2 -0.000 -0.000 0.000 0.400

Energy 2 # with weighting 1.00000000

Atom a b c d
1 0.476 0.000 0.000 0.500
2 0.476 0.000 0.000 0.500
1 0.000 -0.000 -0.000 0.600
2 -0.000 -0.000 0.000 0.600

....

### ....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int rows = 0;
    int columns = 0;
    string line;
    int firstNumber = 0;
    vector<vector<double> > values;
    vector<vector<double> > results;
    vector<double> rowstotal;
    ofstream File;
    ifstream in("data.txt");
    File.open("Output.txt",ios::app);
    File.setf(ios::fixed);
    File.setf(ios::showpoint);
    File.precision(3);

    if(in.fail())
    {
        cerr << "File can not be opened" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    File << "\n" << endl;

    // Save every double
    while(in.good())
    {

        bool begin_tag = false;
        while (getline(in,line))
        {
            if(line.find("Energy   2 #") != std::string::npos ) {
                begin_tag = true;
                continue;
            }
            else if (line == "Energy   1 #")
            {
                begin_tag = false;

            }

            istringstream stream(line);
            vector<double> tmp;
            double x;

            while (stream >> x)
                tmp.push_back(x);

            if (tmp.size() > 0)
                values.push_back(tmp);

        }
    }


    columns = values[0].size();
    for (unsigned i = 1; i < values.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (values[i].size() != columns)
        {
            cerr << "Row with different column number" << endl;
            return -1;
        }
    }

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i)
    {
        // If number with 1.0 is encountered, add it to the row
        if (values[i][0] == 1.0)
            results.push_back(values[i]);

        // If number with 2.0 is encountered, add it also to the row
        if (values[i][0] == 2.0)
        {
            for (unsigned j = 0; j < values[i].size(); ++j)
                results.back()[j] += values[i][j];
        }
    }



    rows = results.size();

    File << "Number of rows # " << rows << endl;
    File << "Number of columns # " << columns << endl;
    File << " " << endl;

    for(int i=0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j=4; j < columns; j++) 
        {
            File << results[i][j]  <<  "     " << "  " << endl;
        }
    }


    for(int i=0; i < rows; i++)
    {  
        rowstotal.push_back(0.0);
        for (int j=1; j < columns; j++) 
        {
            rowstotal[i] += results[i][j];
        }
    }

    File.close();
    in.close();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

Number of rows # 6
Number of columns # 5

0.200
0.400
0.600
0.800
1.000
1.200

As stated above, what I would like to achieve is to sum over only the blocks "Energy   2 #" and ignore the block beginning with "Energy  1#". So the code should give the values:

0.600
0.800
1.000
1.200

I tried to implement a boolean to get it done but somehow I am missing something. I would be really thankful if someone is able to give me a hint or tell me how to solve it.

Thanks for any help and fruitful hints!

Best wishes, 
DaveS

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. I realized that I was setting "begin_tag = false" but was never asking for it.
Thanks again for anyone who read this post and thought about it!